# Установка драйверов USB (win7) после восстановления образа Mucrium Reflect

Tags: windows, usb, драйвер

После восстановления образа Mucrium Reflect Free (ОС Windows 7) на другом железе не работает ни мышь ни клавиатура и нет разъема PS\2, подскажите как интегрировать USB драйвера в образ Mucrium Reflect или установить драйвер в восстановленную систему? Возможно  есть какой-то способ это сделать через командную строку, с помощью LiveCD и т.д.?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена

1. Установил чистую ОС Win7 на этом железе (Сборка Windows 7 SP1 x86-x64 by g0dl1ke 23.6.14 с интегрированными драйверами USB2/3), мышь и клавиатура заработали, установил остальные драйвера с помощью snappy driver installer
2. Загрузился с LiveCD Sergei Strelec, сделал бэкап драйверов с помощью утилиты Dism++ (входит в состав LiveCD Sergei Strelec)
3. Затем снова восстановил образ Macrium Reflect старой системы (Macrium Reflect также входит в состав LiveCD Sergei Strelec), после восстановления образа в Macrium проделываю процедуру ReDeploy Restored image to new hardware чтобы восстановленный образ заработал на новом железе
4. Не выходя из LiveCD Sergei Strelec восстанавливаю драйвера из ранее сделанного бэкапа  на восстановленную систему с помощью той же утилиты Dism++
5. Перезагружаюсь, USB устройства заработали.

Всем спасибо!